# Error When Saving Modules After J3 - J4 Migration

Tags: joomla-4.x, error-handling, logs

Recently migrated a J3 site to J4.2.8

I had to uninstall a lot of plugins before the migration, and a few after, but everything appears to be working apart from one thing.

In the Joomla admin area, wherever I open a module and click 'save' or 'save and close', the following error message is displayed;

> Call to undefined method
> Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication::isSite()

I have set my error reporting to maximum, no additional errors.

I have also set logging to 'everything', when I check administrator/logs/everything.php I see the following;

```
#Software: Joomla! 4.2.8 Stable [ Uaminifu ] 16-February-2023 15:00 GMT

#Fields: datetime   priority clientip   category    message
2023-02-17T14:03:57+00:00   CRITICAL ::1    error   Uncaught Throwable of type Error thrown with message "Call to undefined method Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication::isSite()". Stack trace: #0 [ROOT]\libraries\src\Plugin\CMSPlugin.php(279): plgSystemNRFramework->onExtensionAfterSave('com_modules.mod...', Object(Joomla\CMS\Table\Module), false)
#1 [ROOT]\libraries\vendor\joomla\event\src\Dispatcher.php(486): Joomla\CMS\Plugin\CMSPlugin->Joomla\CMS\Plugin\{closure}(Object(Joomla\Event\Event))
#2 [ROOT]\libraries\src\Application\EventAware.php(107): Joomla\Event\Dispatcher->dispatch('onExtensionAfte...', Object(Joomla\Event\Event))
#3 [ROOT]\administrator\components\com_modules\src\Model\ModuleModel.php(1029): Joomla\CMS\Application\WebApplication->triggerEvent('onExtensionAfte...', Array)
#4 [ROOT]\libraries\src\MVC\Controller\FormController.php(676): Joomla\Component\Modules\Administrator\Model\ModuleModel->save(Array)
#5 [ROOT]\administrator\components\com_modules\src\Controller\ModuleController.php(241): Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\FormController->save('id', 'id')
#6 [ROOT]\libraries\src\MVC\Controller\BaseController.php(672): Joomla\Component\Modules\Administrator\Controller\ModuleController->save()
#7 [ROOT]\libraries\src\Dispatcher\ComponentDispatcher.php(143): Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\BaseController->execute('apply')
#8 [ROOT]\libraries\src\Component\ComponentHelper.php(355): Joomla\CMS\Dispatcher\ComponentDispatcher->dispatch()
#9 [ROOT]\libraries\src\Application\AdministratorApplication.php(143): Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::renderComponent('com_modules')
#10 [ROOT]\libraries\src\Application\AdministratorApplication.php(186): Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->dispatch()
#11 [ROOT]\libraries\src\Application\CMSApplication.php(294): Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->doExecute()
#12 [ROOT]\administrator\includes\app.php(61): Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication->execute()
#13 [ROOT]\administrator\index.php(32): require_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#14 {main}
```

This is the stack when I enable debug.

```
#   Function    Location
1   ()  JROOT\plugins\system\nrframework\nrframework.php:68
2   plgSystemNRFramework->onExtensionAfterSave()    JROOT\libraries\src\Plugin\CMSPlugin.php:279
3   Joomla\CMS\Plugin\CMSPlugin->Joomla\CMS\Plugin\{closure}()  JROOT\libraries\vendor\joomla\event\src\Dispatcher.php:486
4   Joomla\Event\Dispatcher->dispatch() JROOT\libraries\src\Application\EventAware.php:107
5   Joomla\CMS\Application\WebApplication->triggerEvent()   JROOT\administrator\components\com_modules\src\Model\ModuleModel.php:1029
6   Joomla\Component\Modules\Administrator\Model\ModuleModel->save()    JROOT\libraries\src\MVC\Controller\FormController.php:676
7   Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\FormController->save()    JROOT\administrator\components\com_modules\src\Controller\ModuleController.php:241
8   Joomla\Component\Modules\Administrator\Controller\ModuleController->save()  JROOT\libraries\src\MVC\Controller\BaseController.php:672
9   Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\BaseController->execute() JROOT\libraries\src\Dispatcher\ComponentDispatcher.php:143
10  Joomla\CMS\Dispatcher\ComponentDispatcher->dispatch()   JROOT\libraries\src\Component\ComponentHelper.php:355
11  Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::renderComponent() JROOT\libraries\src\Application\AdministratorApplication.php:143
12  Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->dispatch() JROOT\libraries\src\Application\AdministratorApplication.php:186
13  Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->doExecute()    JROOT\libraries\src\Application\CMSApplication.php:294
14  Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication->execute()    JROOT\administrator\includes\app.php:61
15  require_once()  JROOT\administrator\index.php:32
```

I have Advanced Mod Manager and Advanced Template Manager installed but they're both disabled.

Any ideas?

Comment: Topical: [0 Call to undefined method Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication::isAdmin()](https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=812&t=995103) and [after upgrade 3 to 4 Call to undefined method Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication::isSite()](https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=989105) and [0 Call to undefined method Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication::isSite()](https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=994959) Did you see these? Did you do a project-wide search for `isSite()`? and change to `isClient('site')`?

Comment: The NR Framework system plugin is from https://www.tassos.gr/ - do you have one of his extensions installed?  You could try disabling this system plugin especially if you've already disabled the extensions that needed it.

Comment: Thanks @jamesgarrett turns out this is exactly what it was. Strange because all my plugins were up to date. Uninstalling the tassos.gr plugin did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NR Framework system plugin is from tassos.gr. Uninstall of the tassos.gr plugin did the trick.